# Lint warning Suspicious Truncation in arithmetic expression combining with pointer

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, lint

I have the following code:

```
int array[128][3] = { /*lots of emelents there*/}

int* listIt = &array[0][0];

for(unsigned int index = 0 ; index < 128; index++)
{
   printf("%x", array[index*3 + 1]);
}
```

but I got lint warnings like:

```
Suspicious Truncation in arithmetic expression combining with pointer
```

Then I changed the code to

```
array[index*3 + 1u];
```

still get warnings, can someone help me on that?

Comment: `array[something]` is an `int*`, why are you comparing it with an `int`?

Comment: I do not think it is the comparing giving warnings

Comment: Can you help explain why you are testing if a valid pointer is equal to `3`?  A pointer holds a memory address.

Comment: Also, `index` never has a known value.

Comment: I hope you realize that the `n` in `array[n]` is equivalent to `n*3*sizeof(int)` bytes. You're using it like it'll iterate over subarrays. It only iterates over the outer arrays.

Comment: I will update the code

Comment: Try: 'if(array[index][1] == 3)'

Comment: You know `%x` is not for printing pointers? Use `%p` for printing a pointer cast to `void*`.

Comment: why it is a pointer?

Comment: @ratzip When you declare `int foo[128]`; `foo` can be considered an `int*` pointing to the first of 128 allocated `int`s. When you declare `int array[128][3]`; `array` can be considered an `int**` pointing to the first `int[3]` of 128 allocated `int[3]`s. Now bearing in mind that an `int[3]` can just be considered an `int*` *that* is why when you iterate over the first dimension of `array` you are iterating over `int*`s.

Comment: What's this code *supposed* to do? And does it work? You've declared and initialized `listIt`, but you don't use it anywhere, so what is its relevance to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

1) change literal 3 to unsigned, as you did for 1;

2) use indexing in 2D-array style: array[row][col] instead of array[row*col+1].

Answer (score 0):

Lint's warning is correct you are going to index out of bounds with this code.

The line: `printf("%x", array[index*3 + 1]);` Will look at `array[index * 3 + 1]`. When `index` is 44, `index` * 3 + 1 is 133. `array` only has 128 `int[3]` elements this is out of bounds.

It appears that you are trying to print the addresses of the start of each `int[]` in `array`. Try this instead:

```
for(auto it = begin(array); it < end(array); ++it){
    cout << *it;
}
```

Not sure but you may be trying to print the contents rather than the address of each `int[3]` in `array`. If so you could accomplish that like this:

```
for(auto it = begin(array); it < end(array); ++it){
    cout << (*it)[0] << ", " << (*it)[1] << ", " << (*it)[2] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Actually array has 128 × 3 elements, but you are right the ratzip's code skips element `array[0][0]` (i.e. array [0]) and uses element with index 127*3+1, that not exists.

Comment: I've edited the answer to indicate that the elements of the first dimension of `array` are `int[3]`s

Comment: Maybe clarifications about `auto`, `begin` and `end` are also needed (c++ standard, etc.)

Comment: @VolAnd You're going to whip this into a good answer yet! `auto`, `begin`, and `end` are standard C++11 behavior. Explaining them is a bit out of scope for this question. But I agree with the idea of linking to some relevant information. For a general explanation of `auto`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto For `begin`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin And for `end`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end Follow up questions on these probably justify a new question. But if you post a link here I will come try to answer.